# How to save multiple attachments from multiple emails to my desktop using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am brand new to coding and have been working in VBA and SQL. I have been unable to write or find a code that I need. I want the code to be in a macor button in excel. The code needs to be able to search my outlook email and find three emails (The three emails have the same subject every day just a different date in the subject). The code then needs to be able to save the attachments from the email down on my desktop. I was wondering if this was even possible through VBA? I have looked on here for code and have seen some examples but I get multiple errors. I am just looking for a basic framework that I can then use to tweak and build upon. Sorry for the very entry level questions and post with no example code but like I said I am brand new.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: There are a zillion tuts online for this e.g. http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code with an outlook rule to save a specific file to a folder every day.  You'll need to set the rule up to find the correct email with the attachment.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Const saveFolder As String = "C:\Users\tjb1\Desktop"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
Next

Set objAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd propose the following little refactoring of your code (backslashes to limit codelines): `Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)\  Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment\ Const saveFolder As String ="C:\Users\tjb1\Desktop"\ For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments\ objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName\ Next\ Set objAtt = Nothing\ End Sub`

Comment: What do you gain by doing that?  To be honest, I copied this from someone else but it's been a long time.

Comment: it's just a matter of good coding practice: 1)  use constants when you actually have them (this also saves a code line...) 2) avoid statement in loops when they are not needed

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do a VBA macro for Outlook and run it as rule.
Open Outlook and open VBA editor with Alt+F11.

The code below save the only the attachment specified

```
Public Sub saveAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim pos As Integer
saveFolder = "C:\Location\to\be\save\"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    pos = InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Name of the attachment to save")
    If pos <> 0 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The code below save all attachment in a email.

```
 Public Sub saveAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Location\to\be\save\"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
 End Sub
```

After you save that you can create a rule using script.
When creating the rule you need to go in advance option and when you get to select action look for run a script select if and make sure to set it up to run your VBA script Sub named saveAttach or what ever you named it.

I hope this help.

Comment: No option to "run a script." Win 10.